# Powershell - Loop with split and heavy files

Tags: powershell, foreach, split

I have many SFTP log files, about 1gb each, with millions of lines.
I need for each files to extract only accounts that were able to login.

My idea was first to extract from the log files the lines where the accounts appear in a .csv, then to use "Split" to extract just the account, and put it in another .csv.
And, it works... Problem is that with such an amount of data, the split part takes a lot of time and ressources, even for only one file.

Being fairly new to Powershell, I was wondering if there was a better way to do this, or make it run faster.
I guess  my script takes time to run, because each time I extract the account, I write it to the .csv file. Maybe there is a way to write the result to memory, and export it to the .csv file in one block?

Thanks for your help !

```
#Location of sftp logs in .txt
$log_file = get-childitem -name C:\temp\logs_sftp\Logs

#Extraction of lines where an account logged in
foreach ($File in $log_file)
{
get-date
Select-String -Path C:\Temp\logs_sftp\Logs\$file -Pattern "logged in" | select-string -Pattern "230" -NotMatch | select-string -Pattern "530 Not logged in" -NotMatch | Export-Csv C:\Temp\logs_sftp\Logs\$file.csv
get-date
}

#Location of sftp logs with only the account lines in .csv

#Split loop to extract only the account
$log_file_csv = get-childitem -name C:\temp\logs_sftp\Logs\*.csv
foreach ($File in $log_file_csv)
{    
$ToSplit = Get-Content C:\temp\logs_mutualise\Logs\$file | Select-Object -Skip 2
$ToSplit | ForEach-Object {
    $aItems = $_ -split { $_ -eq " "}
    $aItems[$aItems.length-4]  >> C:\Temp\logs_sftp\Result\export_split.csv
    }
}
```

EDIT:
As requested, here is some lines from one of the sftp log (only lines with account)

```
"True","12","[5] Tue 01Nov22 00:00:00 - (63025700) User User_1 logged in","LogsServ-U01112022.txt","C:\Temp\logs_mutualise\Logs\LogsServ-U01112022.txt","logged in",,"System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match[]"
"True","31","[5] Tue 01Nov22 00:00:00 - (63025701) User User_2 logged in","LogsServ-U01112022.txt","C:\Temp\logs_mutualise\Logs\LogsServ-U01112022.txt","logged in",,"System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match[]"
"True","49","[5] Tue 01Nov22 00:00:00 - (63025702) User User_3 logged in","LogsServ-U01112022.txt","C:\Temp\logs_mutualise\Logs\LogsServ-U01112022.txt","logged in",,"System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match[]"
```

I should have precised that the goal is to have a list of users that have been connected at least once on the sftp server.
The files which I extracted this samples is above 700.000 lines.
What I want:

```
User_1
User_2
User_3
```

Comment: The Pattern is Regex and you can get data out of a string in the pattern instead of using split. I need to see samples of the files and output you expect to determine best method in terms of speed and memory usage.  I usually process one line at a time with huge files to minimize memory usage.  I loop through data using a StreamReader

Comment: Samples added in the post

Comment: Run the code while watching Task Manager and check the CPU and Memory.  If memory usage is not reaching 100% than the code is probably ok.  If memory is reaching 100% that swap space is being used and program is going to run slow.  Than changes will be needed to speed up the code.

Comment: Swap space is not use, and computer is running fine. But still, I launch my script about 1h30 ago, and the first file has not yet been processed.
That's why I was hopping for a better way to do it.

I see I did'nt put what I want as a result. Just add it to the post.

Comment: So you're looking to extract `User_1` from `- (63025700) User User_1 logged in` in all logs where the log line does NOT match `530 Not logged in` or `230` correct ?

Comment: What probably is taking time is the creating of the file.  Is your c:\  drive full?  Is it badly fragmented?

Comment: Maybe log to a database.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon Yes, correct

Comment: @jdweng My c:\ drive looks fine, no problem from this side. Other scripts run fine, this one just take very long.

Comment: @js2010 I have no access to a database, and I'm not familiar with it

Answer (score 0):

For those who need it, here is how I do it now:

```
$log_file = get-childitem -name C:\temp\logs_mut\Logs

#loop to extract lines from files
foreach ($File in $log_file)
{
Select-String -Path C:\Temp\logs_mut\Logs\$file -Pattern "logged in" | select-string -Pattern "230" -NotMatch | select-string -Pattern "530 Not logged in" -NotMatch | Export-Csv C:\Temp\logs_mut\Logs\$file.csv
}

#Loop to extract only the account name
$log_file_csv = get-childitem -name C:\temp\logs_mut\Logs\*.csv
foreach ($File in $log_file_csv)
{    
$ToSplit = Get-Content C:\temp\logs_mut\Logs\$file | Select-Object -Skip 2
$ToSplit -replace '"True.+User ','' -replace ' logged.+$','' | sort-object | get-unique >> C:\Temp\logs_mut\Result\$file.result.csv
}
 

#Put results in one file
$date_result = get-date -format ddMMyy
get-content C:\Temp\logs_mut\result\*.csv | sort-object | get-unique >> C:\Temp\logs_mut\final\Logs-$date_result-Result.csv
```

Much faster!

Thank you to all who helped me